# How to reset millis( )?

Tags: arduino-uno, millis

I am currently doing a school project.  There you have to program a stopwatch with the Arduino.  I wrote a program where millis starts.  But when I press my start button, millis don‘t start from 0. 
Has someone an idea? Please let me know.

Ps: I‘m German, so I‘m sorry for my bad English 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Instead you just remember what `millis()` was when you pressed your start button, then subtract that from whatever `millis()` is showing at any other point in the future.

Comment: I‘ve just added a picture of my program, maybe you‘re able to take a look

Comment: @Laurentien Please... don't post photographs of code. Post the *actual* code.

Comment: BTW: millis() returns an **unsigned** long. That will make a difference after 24 days of continuous running. And it will allow running forever, even when that unsigned long will roll over.

Comment: @DataFiddler but doing `stopmillis-startmillis` will always return the correct value if the time between start and stop is less than the 24-day rollover.

Comment: It's a 49+ day rollover.  unsigned long lets millis() return from 0 to 4,294,967,295 mS.  x 1 second/1000mS, x 1 minute/60 seconds, x 1 hour/60 minutes, x 1 day/24 hours = 49.59 days

Comment: @ratchet freak, you're right: The calculation is the same, no matter if interpreted unsigned or signed, so any resulting interval < 24.x days will be positive, even if stopmillis and (in the next period) startmillis become negative.  But negative timestamps (and signed intervals) are harder to imagine. :)